# How to extract frames from a stream record in an UWP C++ project?

Tags: uwp, video-capture, c++-cx

In a UWP C++/CX project, I'm trying to take screenshots from every frame of a MediaCapture Camera Stream and save the stream as a video at the end. My approach:

```
/// <summary>
/// Records an MP4 video to a StorageFile and adds rotation metadata to it
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
task<void> CameraControl::StartRecordingAsyncStream()
{
//InMemoryRandomAccessStream^ video_stream;
// Calculate rotation angle, taking mirroring into account if necessary
auto rotationAngle = CameraRotationHelper::ConvertSimpleOrientationToClockwiseDegrees(_rotationHelper->GetCameraCaptureOrientation());
auto encodingProfile = MediaProperties::MediaEncodingProfile::CreateMp4(MediaProperties::VideoEncodingQuality::Auto);

encodingProfile->Video->Properties->Insert(RotationKey, rotationAngle);


return create_task(_mediaCapture->StartRecordToStreamAsync(encodingProfile, this->video_stream))
    .then([this]()
{
    _isRecording = true;
    WriteLine("Started recording");


}).then([this](task<void> previousTask)
{
    try
    {
        previousTask.get();
    }
    catch (Exception^ ex)
    {
        // File I/O errors are reported as exceptions
        WriteLine(ex->Message);
    }
});
}

/// <summary>
/// Stops recording a video
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
task<void> CameraControl::StopRecordingAsyncStream()
{
_isRecording = false;

WriteLine("Stopping recording...");
return create_task(_mediaCapture->StopRecordAsync())
    .then([this]()
{
    WriteLine("Stopped recording!");

    });
}


//Loads all frames as images from the stream
void CameraControl::LoadVideoStream(void) {

//TODO: Read all Frames as Thumbnails from "this->video_stream" and store them as Bitmaps, for example in a vector

}

/// <summary>
/// Stores the recorded stream as a MP4 video
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
task<void> CameraControl::StoreRecordingAsync()
{

// Create storage file for the capture
return create_task(_captureFolder->CreateFileAsync("SimpleVideo.mp4", CreationCollisionOption::GenerateUniqueName))
    .then([this](StorageFile^ file)
{

//TODO: Write the "this->video_stream" as a MP4 video to the file

});
}
```

For the first question, I need something like an MP4Decoder that can convert the stream (similar to the BitmapDecoder for CapturePhotoToStreamAsync)

To the second question: I know that there is a function "StartRecordToStorageFileAsync". But this is not a solution because to save the video is optionally at the end. I don't want to save every video.

Thanks!

Corono

**EDIT:**

I tried to implement a Media Frame Reader which has an FrameArrived event.

```
public : IAsyncOperation<MediaFrameReader> CreateFrameReaderAsync(MediaFrameSource inputSource)
```

Works well on PC, but there is no MediaFrameSource found on the Win10 mobile devices. No idea why.

Comment: Why do you want take screenshots from every frame of a MediaCapture Camera Stream? It seems we can save the video directly.

Comment: Because I don't want a video, I need a stream of images to analyze a movement step by step. To store the video should just be an option after the analyzation.

Answer (score 0):

The `MediaFrameReader` gives you access to individual frames from a `MediaCapture` as `SoftwareBitmap`. I have done this for processing individual frames in C#, but it should equally work in C++. My code is based on this sample: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/process-media-frames-with-mediaframereader